# Draw squares for a game board in haskell

Tags: haskell, draw, gloss

I would like to be able to draw something like a chess board using haskell and gloss.

In any other language I could do something like

```
for( i=0; i < 10; i++){
   for( j=0; j < 10; j++){
      drawSquare(radius, i, j)
    }
}
```

and that would be it, but I am new to haskell and I have no idea how this can be done. I am using Gloss and I am able to draw things manually, but I want to be able to create them procedurally not 1 by 1 until I draw 100 squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work inside the IO monad, you can use the same style. For instance

```
printSquares :: IO ()
printSquares =
   forM_ [0..9] $ \x ->
      forM_ [0..9] $ \y -> do
         putStrLn "Here's a square!"
         putStrLn ("Square(" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ ")")
         -- add here the actual drawing Gloss commands
```

I'm not familiar with Gloss to suggest the actual drawing commands.

---

Update: it seems Gloss has a different interface than using IO as above. You probably need something like

```
squares :: Picture
squares = Pictures [ square x y | x<-[0..9], y<-[0..9] ]

square :: Float -> Float -> Picture
square x y = Polygon [(x,y), (x+1,y), (x+1,y+1), (x,y+1) ]
   -- even better: use rectangleWire and then translate
   -- rectangleUpperWire also seems useful
```

Comment: Oh, I didnt know you could use the same style, I shall try.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy Actually, I'm unsure about the Gloss interface. Maybe this answer is completely off the track. Maybe in Gloss you have to represent your image as a list/tree of shapes.

Comment: yes it seems that I have to create a Picture, like in this post http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-gloss/ what I couldnt figure out was how to do a board of varaible length sizes and colors. 
the style "[ square x y | x<-[0..9], y<-[0..9] ]" is perfect. I am trying it right now

Comment: Got it! I did a Picture like this

squares :: Picture
squares = Pictures [ (translate x y $ rectangleSolid 1 1) | x<-[0,2..9], y<-[0,2..9] ]

Answer (score 3):

While I am not familiar with the gloss library, you are probably looking for something like a list comprehension:

```
drawBoard :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
drawBoard w h = sequence_ [drawSquare radius i j | i <- [0 .. w], j <- [0 .. h]]
```

Comment: I like this style for defining the range and asigning it to the variable. 
In gloss it seens that you have to draw a "Picture" to send to the render so it looks like this in the end: 
squares :: Picture
squares = Pictures [ (translate x y $ rectangleSolid 1 1) | x<-[0,2..9], y<-[0,2..9] ]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Nitpick: this needs a `sequence_` to be applied to the list of `IO` actions.